# Restore data from one Windows edition to another

Tags: windows-7, backup, restore, language

I have a Swedish Windows 7 Home Premium on my PC, and I really want to change system language to English. I know that Home Premium can't change system language (only W7 Ultimate does that), so I consider buying an English version and make a clean install. However I do have many settings, programs etc that I don't want to lose.
I therefore have two questions:

1. Can I take a backup of my Swedish W7 Home Premium, install the English W7 Home Premium and then restore everything back to normal, except the system language is now English?
2. Can I take a backup of my Swedish W7 Home Premium, install W7 Ultimate and then restore everything back to normal (now with the option to change system language)?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd take the plunge and buy the Ultimate edition anytime upgrade. There's no telling what may or may not work if you restore.

Comment: Oh. That's really not a bad idea at all... Hm. :P

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Vistalizator](http://www.froggie.sk/) which can swap the language pack on home premium.

Windows includes a tool called 'Windows Easy Transfer' to help transfer stuff between installs.